# L'internationale

Tags: grammaire

D'après le [CNRTL](https://cnrtl.fr/synonymie/internationale), le mot "internationale" ne peut être que la forme féminine de l'adjectif "international".
Cependant dans le poème d'Eugène Pottier il est précédé d'un article défini.

Est-ce que cette substantivation est correcte? Si oui, quel est le nom sous-entendu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'après [l'encycolopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Internationale), « à l'origine, il s'agit d'un poème à la gloire de l'Internationale ouvrière, écrit par le chansonnier, poète et goguettier Eugène Pottier en juin 1871, en pleine répression de la Commune de Paris ».
 Si l'on cherche ce que « l'Internationale ouvrière » signifie on trouve  ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_internationale_des_travailleurs)) qu'il s'agit d'une association; c'est l'Association internationale des travailleurs (AIT), nom officiel de **la Première Internationale**, fondée le 28 septembre 1864 à Londres au Saint-Martin's Hall.

De plus on trouve  la définition de ce terme dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/internationale) au « **B 1. a)** ».

> B. POLITIQUE
>
> 1. Adj. et subst. fém. [Souvent avec une majuscule]
>      a) La 1re, 2e, 3e, 4e Internationale ou Association internationale des travailleurs; p. ell. l'Internationale. Association internationale de travailleurs, dont le but est l'union de tous les travailleurs, sans distinction de nationalité, pour la défense de leurs revendications communes.

C'est donc un terme qui nomme par ellipse *l'Association internationale des travailleurs*.

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit à l'origine de l'**Association Internationale des Ouvriers**, puis **Association Internationale Ouvrière**, rapidement raccourcie en **Internationale Ouvrière** (cf. SFIO) puis simplement **Internationale**, comme c'était déjà le cas dans le poème en question.

La première internationale a été fondée à Londres par des hommes politiques et des syndicalistes français, anglais, irlandais, polonais, italiens, belges, suisses, etc. et allemands, dont un certain Karl Marx, sous le nom ***International Working Men's Association***.

[image]

Source: http://www.histoiresocialedeslandes.org/def_internationale_win.asp